# Multiple resizing in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to make two images of a single loaded picture. This images must have fixed width, - 180 and 300 pixels.

At the bottom of my current results. This function can resize and create just one of two images. Everybody failed on second image, I trying whole day, but I'm can't find reason. Need help.

```
$this->_resize($data['upload_data']['file_name'], 300);
$this->_resize($data['upload_data']['file_name'], 180);
private function _resize($file_name, $size) {
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = 'img/upload/' . $file_name;
            $config['dest_image'] = base_url() . 'img/';
            $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
            $config['thumb_marker'] = '_' . $size;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
            $config['width'] = $size;
            $config['height'] = $size;
            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
            $result = $this->image_lib->resize();

            $this->image_lib->clear();
            return;
        }
```

I'm use CodeIgniter 2.02

Comment: It looks like it could be a problem with where you're saving the image. I don't see the option 'dest_image' in the docs, maybe you should set $config['new_image'] instead? -- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html

Comment: 'thumb_marker' will do the path...

Comment: I had been change as you said, but server return access error (Unable to save the image. Please make sure the image and file directory are writable.).

Comment: And one impotant notice, when I'm erase "$this->image_lib->clear();" error "Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image." is disappeared.

Comment: I've guessed, if you want resize images in loop you must initialize library BEFORE and clear() will be work correct. Full solution here - http://pastebin.com/DipFxCC6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nill

Think that problem takes place because on the first run your script moves initial file to another folder. Try to use:

```
$config['new_image'] = base_url() . 'img/';
```

instead of

```
$config['dest_image'] = base_url() . 'img/';
```

Comment: Unable to save the image. Please make sure the image and file directory are writable.

Unable to save the image. Please make sure the image and file directory are writable.

Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.

Comment: And dumb question but you have GD installed?)

Answer (score 16):

Dont load image_lib multiple times. Add image_lib in autoload libs and change

```
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
```

to

```
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
```

Comment: This really worked, CI has really bad documentation

Answer (score 5):

This could help you, from user guide

> A good practice is use the processing
>   function conditionally, showing an
>   error upon failure, like this:
>
> ```
> if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
> {
>     echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
> }
> ```

Comment: Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.

Comment: It's sent to me in second iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself this problem. In my case, I put the image source and new_image without base_url or REAL_PATH:

```
public function create_thumbnail($file_name='2012_02_23_15_06_00_1.jpg'){
    $this->layout = false;
    $image_url = PATH_TO_IMAGE_ARTICLE.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = 'assets/img/content/article/'.$file_name;
    $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 210;
    $config['height'] = 160;    
    $config['new_image'] = 'assets/img/content/article/thumb/thumb_' .  $file_name;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
    {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();exit;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

See?
you don't put

```
$config['new_image'] = base_url().'assets/img/content/article/thumb/thumb_' .  $file_name;
```

but

```
$config['new_image'] = 'assets/img/content/article/thumb/thumb_' .  $file_name;
```

Comment: using base_url(), either your image_source or your new_image will have prefix `http://domain_or_localhost`.

using REAL_PATH like C://htdocs/blablabla/ just complicate things such as unwritable, etc, etc